# Removing X-Powered-By

Tags: php, http-headers

1. How can I remove X-Powered-By header in PHP? I am on an Apache Server and I use php 5.21.
   I can't use the header_remove function in php as it's not supported by 5.21. I used Header unset X-Powered-By, it worked on my local machine, but not on my production server.
2. If php doesn't support header_remove() for ver < 5.3, is there an alternative?

Comment: PHP Version on production: PHP/5.2.13 PHP Version on local: PHP/5.2.11 Apache version on production: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) Apache version on local: Apache 2.0.63 (using MAMP on Mac)

Answer (score 289):

I think that is controlled by the `expose_php` setting in [PHP.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php):

```
expose_php = off
```

> Decides whether PHP may expose the fact that it is installed on the server (e.g. by adding its signature to the Web server header). It is no security threat in any way, but it makes it possible to determine whether you use PHP on your server or not.

There is no direct security risk, but as David C notes, exposing an outdated (and possibly vulnerable) version of PHP may be an invitation for people to try and attack it.

Comment: 'It is no security threat in any way'. This might be untrue for older versions of php running on a hosted server. I've heard that hackers can exploit well documented 'holes' in past versions. It is better to hide this fact....

Comment: Or advertise that you are fully up-to-date and patched up and not to even try anything funny.

Comment: Being "fully up-to-date" is a false positive imo. It's better to disable the information altogether. It's possible that a version released yesterday could already have an exposed threat, and depending on how aggressive your upgrade cycle is, may be so for some time. Better to keep them guessing altogether. I hide as much as I can including nginx versions as well.

Comment: @David, What he means is it does not **add** to the security threat that you already face.

Comment: You can and should purposefully report a bad value for the X-Powered-By header. For example if you are running PHP, you could send a X-Powered-By: ASP.NET header as a way to slow down attackers from ID'ing the software configuration on your web server. Send your attackers down a wild goose chase to slow down their scans.

Comment: I tried using `php_flag expose_php off` in `httpd.conf` and it does not seem to be effective. I believe this setting must be made in `php.ini`.

Comment: @Pacerier, of course it adds to the security threat. Hacker scans 1000's of sites looking for easy prey... having this header when on an old version means the server now gets targeted when previously would have been ignored. It adds to the security threat in a direct way. Even keeping up to date, it could add to the threat in a brief window of time where there is an update that has not been applied yet.

Comment: Arguably bots these days don't test headers to ensure hacks will work, they just try regardless. Hiding an old version of PHP (even if it is recent) doesn't really change anything other than providing for a false peace of mind.

Answer (score 90):

```
header_remove("X-Powered-By");
```

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.header-remove.php

Comment: This solution work from php, `expose_php = off` don't work in .htaccess nor php file.

Answer (score 60):

If you cannot disable the [*expose_php* directive](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.expose-php) to mute PHP’s talkativeness (requires access to the *php.ini*), you could use [Apache’s `Header` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html#header) to remove the header field:

```
Header unset X-Powered-By
```

Comment: That isn't working on my production server. It's working on my local machine though. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: @Castor What server versions are you using locally and on the production machine? Any differences in the PHP setup?

Comment: PHP Version on production: PHP/5.2.13
PHP Version on local: PHP/5.2.11

Apache version on production: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Apache version on local: Apache 2.0.63 (using MAMP on Mac)

Comment: @Castor: Is mod_headers available on both servers? And are you allowed to override *FileInfo* (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride)?

Comment: @Gumbo Yes, mod_headers is available on both the servers. And yes, I am allowed to override FileInfo.

Comment: @Castor: Hm, then I don’t see any reason why this wouldn’t work.

Comment: @Gumbo, how do we do this for the Date and Server headers? unset doesn't seem to work

Comment: Even if you don't have access to Apache configuration (well, if you can't change php.ini, probably you can't change Apache config files) this can be set in a .htaccess file. However I think is still easier to just use PHP's header_remove in your web application.

Comment: How do we remove date and time in the response ?

Comment: Old but evidently still relevant. This worked for me as my host said they turned of expose_php and it was still showing. I tried different ways of writing it out in .htaccess to no luck until this.

Answer (score 27):

```
if (function_exists('header_remove')) {
    header_remove('X-Powered-By'); // PHP 5.3+
} else {
    @ini_set('expose_php', 'off');
}
```

Answer (score 18):

If you have an access to php.ini, set `expose_php = Off`.

Comment: Well, I got this working from the php code. 
header("X-Powered-By: "); 
Setting the X-Powered-By header to nothing removed it.

Thanks all for your time and suggestions.

Answer (score 8):

Try adding a header() call before sending headers, like:

```
header('X-Powered-By: Our company\'s development team');
```

regardless of the expose_php setting in php.ini

Answer (score 6):

If you use FastCGI try:

```
fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;
```

Answer (score 2):

To hide X-Powered-By: PHP/7.x.x , if you are using Share Hosting, VPS, Cloud Server then add the following code in .htaccess file

```
Header always unset X-Powered-By
Header unset X-Powered-By
```

Work well for: `Wordpress, Codeigniter, Laravel, Php`

Answer (score -3):

This solution worked for me :)

Please add below line in the script and check.

Ngnix / Apache etc level settings might not be required.

```
header("Server:");
```

Comment: Because the `Server` header is added by Apache or nGinx, it's not possible to change it from the PHP. Also, the OP asked to remove the `X-Powered-By`.