# Alternative to header_remove

Tags: php, header

I know that header_remove doesn't work in php versions < 5.3 and I use 5.2.1. I am looking for an alternative to header_remove to remove the X-Powered-By header.

I tried using header("X-Powered-By: "); but it still generates a blank header. I tried using Header unset X-Powered-By in .htaccess, but for some reason it's not working. I am stuck here.

Comment: expose\_php is an option that can only be set in the .ini file. For apache `header unset` directive to work mod\_header must be installed and you must have FileInfo override privileges. I don't see any other way to remove that header, good for you if I'm wrong ;-)

Comment: @Castor: Have you tried setting the header with no trailing space? `header("X-Powered-By:");`.  I always thought this was how headers were unset in older versions of PHP.  You could always just leave it in and change it to something bogus: `header("X-Powered-By: Fairies!");`

Comment: I don't understand why you created a new question for this. Just comment on or edit your previous one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661799/removing-x-powered-by see also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318806/hiding-phps-x-powered-by-header

Comment: The purpose of this question is to find out an alternative to header_remove as mentioned in the subject.

Comment: Which is the same purpose as your other question. I quote: *If php doesn't support header_remove() for ver < 5.3, is there an alternative?*

Comment: I really wish there was an alternative to header_remove() in this ticket!

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there is no replacement for this function, but you can either alter the result to something bogus as described above, or configure php.ini to block this header with the following statement:

```
expose_php = Off
```

Comment: I don't have access to php.ini as I am on a shared hosting on Apache.