# How can I disable PHP's "easter egg" URLs?

Tags: php

I recently found out about the so-called ["easter egg URLs"](http://www.0php.com/php_easter_egg.php) in PHP:

> These are the four QUERY strings you can add to the end of a PHP web page to view a (somewhat) hidden image or web page:

1. `?=PHPE9568F36-D428-11d2-A769-00AA001ACF42`

> This one is the most interesting, and displays an "easter egg" image
>   of either a rabbit in a house (Sterling Hughes' rabbit, named
>   Carmella), a brown dog in the grass, a black Scottish Terrier dog, a
>   sloppy child hand-drawn, crayon-colored php logo, a guy with
>   breadsticks (looks like pencils or french fries) sticking out of his
>   mouth like a walrus, or a PHP elephant logo.

[image]

Others include:

- `?=PHPE9568F34-D428-11d2-A769-00AA001ACF42` (PHP Logo)
- `?=PHPE9568F35-D428-11d2-A769-00AA001ACF42` (Zend logo)
- `?=PHPB8B5F2A0-3C92-11d3-A3A9-4C7B08C10000` (PHP Credits)

I was shocked to discover that this does work on a lot of websites, including my own. I think this is idiotic and want to disable it, but from what I hear the only way to do it is in php.ini with `expose_php = Off`, and it [can't be set at runtime](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) with `ini_set()`.

**I don't have direct access to php.ini on the live server.** I have, however, figured out how to unset the `X-Powered-By` header by using [`Header unset X-Powered-By`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2661808/398242) in `.htaccess`, or `header('X-Powered-By: ')` in the PHP code.

Is there any other way I can disable these "easter eggs", or do I have to get this setting changed in the main `php.ini` (and is that indeed the correct/only way to disable these URLs)?

Comment: They don't hurt anyone, so why bother?

Comment: Because I think it's stupid, and exposes the fact that you're using PHP.

Comment: The way I see it, if you want to use an entire engine that people invested a lot of time in to, and all they want in return is to leave a few harmless easter eggs in there, then why not? :D It's fun. I bet you had fun even just looking them up!

Comment: Yep, it was fun - but the fun is over. I'm not sure why you're telling me I need to leave them in.

Comment: I wasn't. I was asking WHY you wanted them gone (as I would for any other question, intention is important). You edited your comment long after I asked the question, so now I know the why, I feel more inclined to help. :)

Comment: The easter eggs are stupid, but disabling will not hide the fact you are using PHP.

Comment: How about the `.user.ini` or `php_value` for mod_php?

Comment: @Nadnartigan I agree with the "I think it's stupid". Furthermore, I think it is stupid that @ DanRedux is suggesting that they don't hurt anyone. I believe its unprofessional, and slightly obnoxious that you should suggest that he shouldn't remove them from a PHP project.

Comment: People "not knowing it's php" is NOT a good measure to prevent any kind of abuse or hacking.

Comment: Why so much upvotes for such  silly question? One who is really concerned of security should avoid a shared hosting in the first place. But fear of these poor eggs is not security concern but illiterate superstition.

Comment: I have just turned on my PHP in-house server and started access logging in the very first day. When I went back home I realize somebody has already accessed those "stupid" pages and the search engine lead me here so I know what the story is. Is that means there are enough people (kind or bad) that are idle enough to look for php sites for fun or for attack?

Comment: @WesleyMurch I don't understand how it can be not shared hosting. A "domain" is the website's name (example.com), do you have control over the *machine* that is hosting your site? If you don't, and it's rented, it's probably shared hosting (i.e., even if they give you a user account and PhpMyAdmin/cPanel, it does not mean you are not sharing the server).

Comment: NOTE: None of these easter eggs are present in PHP versions >= 5.5.0

Comment: Using these easter eggs, you can discover the version of PHP and use it to know the vulnerabilities.  [This site](https://labs.detectify.com/2012/10/29/do-you-dare-to-show-your-php-easter-egg) says it all.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A quick HTACCESS global rewrite could regex the exact string right out of every URL thus getting rid of the only fun part of PHP without touching the ini file nor needing a function at the beginning of every file.

Haven't tested this yet, but this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \PHPE9568F36-D428-11d2-A769-00AA001ACF42\ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Of course, just copy the last 2 lines for each of the other possible queries, or write a more generic regex. I'm not good with regex. :)

This version covers all of the easter egg fun and was found [here:](https://akeeba.assembla.com/code/master-htaccess/git/nodes/htaccess.txt)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \=PHP[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12} [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Comment: Any clue how exactly to do that? I can research it myself, but if you can provide an example to get rid of one of the URLs that would be a big help. Any idea as to whether the ini directive I quoted is actually correct, and would get rid of these things?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, this particular rule gives me "internal server error", but the other comment's link (which is now deleted) had one that seemed to work: https://akeeba.assembla.com/code/master-htaccess/git/nodes/htaccess.txt Under "Disallow PHP Easter Eggs" Feel free to add it in to your post for others!

Comment: Yes, the ini directive DOES hide all signs of PHP life, including the 5 easter egg url's (the 4 you mentioned, and the 1 that executes a MySQL query with the GET parameter "query" if MySQL is installed).

Comment: Is there a sixth one that just deletes your entire application?

Comment: No, PHP only has 5. You might be thinking of the CGI easter eggs.

Comment: Just one more thing I could use help with if you don't mind (I can fiddle with it myself later if you aren't sure). How could I instead of `RewriteRule .* - [F]` which gives a 403 error, just have it ignore the query string and load the page? Or is that not possible because of the nature of this thing? (I know, it's silly to "optimize" something like this)

Comment: I'm not totally sure, although it seems like a 403 would be a good way to respond to people doing something so idiotic as to try and have fun, in my opinion.

Comment: Actually, the fact that that link with the rewrite rule even exists leads me to believe there is no other way besides editing php.ini, so I guess this must be the only solution under these conditions. Thanks again.

Comment: So what happens of someone wants to deploy the app on IIS+Windows?

Comment: @SalmanA: Then if this is important to you, you'd need to use the IIS equivalent of mod_rewrite - or the real way, in php.ini

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? `expose_php` is the proper way to turn them off.

Comment: @AndreaFaulds: this is the accepted answer because the asker already explained (with reference) that one can only set `expose_php` in php.ini and that the op doesn't have access to that file so he can't use that solution. However, as of php 5.5 the easter-eggs (and their code that waisted 21KB memory per instance of php) is finally removed: http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.incompatible.php#migration55.incompatible.guid **PS** I'd love that someone post a link to that mysterious 5'th link.. I like fifth elements haha.

Comment: @GitaarLAB: Guess who was responsible for submitting the patch removing those easter eggs? It was yours truly :)

Answer (score 60):

in php.ini

```
; Decides whether PHP may expose the fact that it is installed on the server
; (e.g. by adding its signature to the Web server header).  It is no security
; threat in any way, but it makes it possible to determine whether you use PHP
; on your server or not.
; http://php.net/expose-php
 expose_php = Off
```

This will effectively remove the easter eggs

Comment: The OP said "I don't have direct access to php.ini on the live server."

Comment: Although it doesn't answer the OP's question, it's still useful for people stumbling across this question who do have access to php.ini.

Comment: If you don't have access to the php.ini you should report this to the system administrator to get this setting turned off on a production environment. So I will recommend this answer.

Comment: Your server administrator might not turned it off because many applications like cpanel etc need it.

Answer (score 10):

Update: This is removed in PHP 5.5, note how these links no longer work on php.net

http://phpsadness.com/sad/11