# PHP Credits page

Tags: php

I would like to disable the "PHP credit page" accessible using `/?=PHPB8B5F2A0-3C92-11d3-A3A9-4C7B08C10000` at the end of any website page URL in order to validate the PCI compliance test.

I already turned off expose_php to "Off" and restarted the server, but it doesn't seems to be of any use on this part.

`php -i | grep "expose_php"` is giving me 
`expose_php => Off => Off` and all the others "Easter eggs" have been disabled.

Comment: use mod_rewrite to redirect it to / or strip the GUID?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458610/how-can-i-disable-phps-easter-egg-urls