# Slashes after .php

Tags: php, post, wireshark

I'm trying to analyse the packets sent by an application through WireShark and I came across this line:

```
POST /main.php/login/authkey HTTP/1.1
```

**Question:** 
1. Is `main.php` a directory or a php file?
2. Is `authkey` a php file? Related to `.htaccess`?

Sorry if this question was asked before, but I don't know how to describe this to search with.

EDIT:
The response given is: `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`
Server is apache

Comment: Learn about Apache server `mod_rewrite` and check your page's `.htaccess` file. We can't answer this question without config and files structure provided.

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk not helpful since if it's apache there's no mod rewrite needed for that kind of request to work.

Comment: This looks pretty much like [PATH_INFO](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3875#section-4.1.5) to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to authoritatively tell what the server does with any given URL, but the most likely answers are:

1. A PHP file
2. It is *something* which is interpreted by the code in `main.php` (via `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`).

Comment: It can be said though, that it used to be a rather standard technique for "pretty" urls without relying on mod rewrite. +1.

Answer (score 0):

What you see is the request. As the server can parse at anyway it wants (e.g.: redirect all requests to `/index.asp`) there is no answer to be given.

We can however guess a bit. Possibilies are that `main.php` is a script, that uses the '/login/authkey' url-part to start expecting a post for the functionality login (using an authkey perhaps?)

It can be that a `.htaccess` file either redirects the request to a file called `main.php` (seems likely from the name), or that it first redirects to some sort of index, that finds the part about `main.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, `main.php` can be a directory, too. From the request line alone, it can not be said at all. Same applies to `authkey`, it could be a PHP file as well. However only from request URI path alone, you actually can not say nothing but just speculate. Instead, you need to look into the server configuration and then look-up the files / directories on the server itself.

To make this more prominent: The response could be a 404. You're not providing any response information.

Apart from that, it's a common feature of the Apache webserver that requests with URI paths that contain a PHP file will get passed along to that PHP file.

Comment: The response given is `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` the server accepted it. That is why I'm confused

Comment: Do you have an X-Powered-By header in the response? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661799/removing-x-powered-by

Comment: Yes there is. It says `Native APP Platform`. Maybe this is not a PHP server?