# How to protect PHP website from Server Banner Grabbing

Tags: php, apache

I have a website made on PHP version 7. My website is vulnerable to server banner grabbing. How can we solve this?

I have tried adding the following directives in Apache configuration file/etc/apache2/httpd.conf

```
ServerTokens Prod
ServerSignature Off
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with php or mysql, nor programming or software development in general. There is a security sister site of SO, they are the experts in cyber security matters.

Comment: Please read more about website security and then try to aply some options that you find. Then after trying hard to solve this situation, put here the code where you got stuck.

Answer (score -1):

For HTTP communications, server banners are transmitted as HTTP headers. These come as name/value pairs like `Server: Apache`. PHP is known for adding an `X-Powered-By` header to each page, containing the PHP version as the value. For removing it, see

[Hiding PHP's X-Powered-By header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318806)